# subquery or join?

Tags: mysql, sql, dbvisualizer

I am using subquery and join to execute this statement: 
SHOW ALL THE JOB TITLES THAT EXIST IN FINANCE DEPARTMENT (DO NOT REPEAT ANY JOB TITLES)

my Join works and I get right output, but subquery doesn't and I can't see an error
output gives me this :

[image: error message]

```
select DISTINCT(job_title) 
from jobs 
where job_id = (select job_id from employees 
                where department_id = 
                (select department_id from departments
                where department_name like 'finance'))



select DISTINCT(job_title) from jobs j
inner join employees e 
on j.job_id = e.job_id
inner join departments d
on d.department_id = e.department_id
where department_name like 'finance'
```

Comment: `=` compares 1 value to one value.  The result of your sub query could be many job ID's.  Therefore you can't use `=` nor `!=` for a comparison.  you could use `IN` however instead of `=`

Comment: use IN instead of  =

Comment: @PatrickHonorez yes, it works now. Thank you, I didnt see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, you probably want:

```
select DISTINCT(job_title) 
from jobs 
where job_id IN (select job_id from employees 
                where department_id IN 
                (select department_id from departments
                where department_name like 'finance'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the subquery alone it shold show you more than one row.

As you are doing an equal (job_id = something), that something, as it is a query, is has to deliver a single value as a result which implicitly can't come in more than one row).